# Reading characters in a background application

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I'm trying to make a simple program that read keys from keyboard even if my application is running in the background.

**Situation**
I want make a timer to help me in a game. I already have the program with the timer, the problem is I can not start the timer without switching of the game window to my app window. So I configured the game keyboard to release the keys F11, F12. Now in game this keys do nothing.

**Problem**
I built a windows forms containing a listener for keydown event and a conditional for F11. But when I trigger another window (eg the game window) my application no longer hears the keyboard, cuz it's in the background.

**Question**
How can I build a app that hears the keyboard, even if it's not active window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install a [global, low-level keyboard hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using the [SetWindowHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API call. Using the **WH_KEYBOARD_LL** hook will set your application up to intercept keyboard events at all times, even when your application is not active.

[This post on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx) shows an example of how to achieve something close to what you want from C#.